# Cannot access .withAutomaticReconnect function in SignalR v1.1.4

Tags: react-native, websocket, signalr

I saw that the automatic redirect has been implemented in signalR js client. I've updated signalR to version 1.1.4 and after that I tried to create new hubConnectionbuilder like this:

```
this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.None)
      .withUrl(REMOTE_SOCKET_ENDPOINT, options)
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();
```

I am working on mobile application and when I run it, it throws error, saying that withAutomaticReconnect is not a function. I also noticed that this function is not visible when typing. What could be the reason for not seeing the function when I am creating the hub connection ? Thank you!

Comment: did you get tihs resolved? Im having the same issue

Comment: No. Still searching for solution

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Version 1.1.4 doesn't contain withAutomaticReconnect. Version 3.0.0 is the latest version for .net core. I had this problem and npm install @microsoft/signalr@latest solved this.

Comment: also make sure you update your import statement, I was using @aspnet/signalr, but now its import { HubConnectionBuilder } from '@microsoft/signalr';